# "Redirect has been blocked by CORS policy" Vue Axios

Tags: vue.js, cors, axios

Please don't mark this as a duplicate. I have read every related answer on stack overflow and have yet to come to a clear solution for this issue.

I'm using a vue server right now with axios to try to fetch data and display it from https://coinmarketcap.com. The problem is that I get an error message in the chrome console:

> Redirect from 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker' to
>   'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource. Origin 'http://mywebsite.ca' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

My function is as barebones as possible, in line with documentation and online tutorial. In my vue component script section:

```js
methods: {
      async getCryptos() {
        await axios.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker').then((resp) => {
          this.response = resp.data
        }).catch((err) => {
          this.response = err
        })
      }
    },
    beforeMount () {
      this.getCryptos()
    }
```

I've read countless documentation on this subject and have yet to find a clear answer. I have no idea what headers to include but I have tried many combinations of configuration. Can someone succinctly explain what it is that I need to do here? I know other websites fetch from coinmarketcap, so it is possible. It shouldn't be that difficult...

Comment: Have you tried adding yourself the trailing slash on your request to avoid the redirection?

Comment: Oh.... my.... god.... (edit: to clarify my response, that actually fixed it. I can't thank you enough, what a stupid error. I will give you the answer if you post)

Comment: Don't worry. We all miss stuff like that from time to time. It's part of the job! lol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.\[website\].com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed my issue by adding the slash (`/`) at the end of my API request. I've been getting the same warning at my console log but it's working now.