# How to transform perfect devServer config file for production server. Because locally no error and after deploy cors error

Tags: vue.js, deployment, configuration, devops, config

The below code is working fine locally on chrome and firefox without installing the cors plugin. However, when I create a build and place a static file to a production server droplet at /var/www/html It's not working. Please let me know how to change this config file for production and I don't get cors error as well. like not getting cors or any error locally.

This is my vue.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
    "/one": {
    target: "https://etherscan.io/",
    pathRewrite: { "^/one": "" },
    },
    "/two": {
    target: "https://bscscan.com/",
    pathRewrite: { "^/two": "" },
    },
    },
    },
};
```

Moreover, This is the request:

```
         this.$http
                .get("http://localhost:8080/one/token/" + this.contractAddress, {
                  mode: "no-cors",
                  header: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080/",
                  },
                  gzip: true,
                })
```

The second request in the same component is:

```
           this.$http
                    .get("http://localhost:8080/two/token/" + this.contractAddress, {
                      mode: "no-cors",
                      header: {
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080/",
                      },
                      gzip: true,
                    })
```

Error after deployment, when I open deployed app by IP address:

[image]

Then I tried to replace http://localhost:8080 to http//:localhost in URL and at access control allow origin I placed http://ip or server/ Then Error

[image]

Comment: This is because of the cors policy on your server. You need to create one. If you are using express you can use `npm i express-cors` then `app.use(cors())`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Redirect has been blocked by CORS policy" Vue Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718255/redirect-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-vue-axios)

Comment: @SuitBoyApps Thanks for your comment. Actually, it's a vue.js front-end app. Not using any express server.